# Como posso publicar todos o branchs do git de uma só vez para meu repositório remoto no github?

Tags: git, github

Tenho vários branchs que criei no meu git (aula1, aula2, aula3) que são variações do mesmo arquivo index.html, mas quando vou enviar para o github consigo enviar apenas o master

Existe alguma forma de enviar todos os branchs de uma só vez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é entrar em cada *branch* para saber o que está sendo enviado, mas o jeito mais simples é:

```
git push --all
```

> --all
>   Faz push de todas as branchs (i.e. refs sobre refs/heads/); não pode ser usada com outro `<refspec>`